# how to get value on key strock/press?

Tags: java

I need to create a program which fire event on every key press(like key logger). I couldn't able to get key value. This program will run behind and on every key press it fire event. I didn't find any thing related to this on net.

Comment: Is it _like_ a key logger or is it _actually_ a key logger? When you say the program "will run behind and on every key press...", it sounds like a key logger. If it's different, could you explain how it's going to work?

Comment: Add a `java.awt.event.KeyListener` to whatever Component you are wishing to track the key presses of.  If you are trying to create an OS-wide key listener, you will need to use native libraries such as JNI.

Comment: @Dynguss yes you can say that it is actually a key logger. But it works slightly different, it keeps record of every box rather than mail you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very strange that you cannot find anything.
You should user `KeyListener` to log key events. If only one event (e.g. keyUP, keyDown or keyPress) is relevant use `KeyAdapter` instead.

The problem is that key listener can be attached to any java screen element and catches events dispatched to this element only. For example you can create Frame and add key listener to it and capture all key events withing this frame.

You cannot capture key events outside the java application.

If you still want to do this you can use the following work-around. Create transparent window and add listener to it. The listener should catch events, log them and then imitate them on the same location on screen using `java.awt.Robot`.

This reference will help you to create transparent window: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Other way is to use JNI/JNA directly or indirectly. For example xdotools can help you.